# How does the renormalization process differ between actions with and without diffeomorphism invariance?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, effective-field-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

If I have an action that is not invariant under a change of coordinates. Does this effect the renormalizability of the theory?

The procedure of renormalizing a field theory essentially boils down to carefully keeping track of observables while changing the length scale of the theory. If I have an action that is not diffeomorphism invariant changing the scaling of the action has physical meaning and also has consequences on the parameterization of the theory.

How does the renormalization process differ between actions with and without coordinate invariance?

Comment: Most renormalizable theories don't even have an action.